# Xamarin.Forms update Entry value from Xamarin.Essentials.Contacts selection using MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to update the value of an Entry control using Xamarin.Essentials.Contacts.

I have a `PhoneNumber` Entry that's empty when opening the page but there's a button below it that says 'Select Contact' and I'm retrieving the phone number and am trying to set the value of the `PhoneNumber` Entry to that phone number.

I can't seem to be able to do it and I don't really know how to do it.

When I select the contact I get the number but it doesn't update the Entry value.

Here's my code

XAML

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="16,12"
                                 Spacing="12">
                    <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                               Padding="6, 1"
                               Margin="5, 0"
                               CornerRadius="8"
                               BackgroundColor="#212121">
                        <Entry x:Name="PhoneNumberEntry"
                               Text="{Binding PhoneNumberEntry, Mode=TwoWay}"
                               Placeholder="Don't add '+1'" 
                               Keyboard="Numeric"
                               MaxLength="10"
                               Style="{StaticResource EntryStyle}" />
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 Padding="16,12"
                                 Spacing="12">
                    <Button x:Name="ContactButton"
                               Text="Or select contact"
                                Command="{Binding SelectContactCommand}"
                            BackgroundColor="Red"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel

```
public class InviteViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public InviteViewModel()
    {
        SelectContactCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteSelectContactCommand());
        Info = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public string PhoneNumberEntry { get; set; }
    public Command SelectContactCommand { get; set; }
    public StringBuilder Info { get; set; }

    private async Task ExecuteSelectContactCommand()
    {
        try
        {
            var contact = await Contacts.PickContactAsync();
            if (contact == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Info.AppendLine(contact.Phones.FirstOrDefault()?.PhoneNumber ?? string.Empty);
            var phoneNumber = Info.ToString().Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "").TrimEnd();
            PhoneNumberEntry = phoneNumber;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `PhoneNumberEntry` is getting updated?  You have an empty `catch` block so if there is any exception you would never know.  Also, `Entry` is a single line control, but you are appending a newline with `StringBuilder`.  For this use case a `StringBuilder` is probably overkill

Comment: Ok let me try differently

Comment: So I changed the StringBuilder to a string and added a breakpoint at the catch block and nothing changed

Comment: but does `PhoneNumberEntry` actually get assigned the value that you think it does?

Comment: I think it's that you are just missing a notifypropertychanged when you update the PhoneNumberEntry property?

Comment: @AppPack I was thinking about it too but since the ViewModel is inheriting `BaseViewModel` which has `INotifyPropertyChanged` already I thought that was enough, should I add it in the `PhoneNumberEntry` setter ? @Jason I don't think it does because it never hits the setter nor the getter after the `ExecuteSelectContactCommand` method

Comment: yes you should add it to the setter, the event is not called automatically so you will need setter logic to launch the event correctly. usually the baseviewmodel class has a method like "RaisePropertyChanged" that will fire the event correctly

Comment: `BaseViewModel` provides the `PropertyChanged` method, but you still have to call it in your setter.  You could also hardcode an initial value for the property just to verify that the binding is working.  You can easily test if the property is set by adding a `Console.Writeline()` after it is set, or using a breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: If you get this working based on comments above, please add "Your Answer" below, showing the working code. This will help others in the future. :)

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much guys

Answer (score 1):

Like @Jason and @AppPack said, it was only a matter of using `OnPropertyChanged()` in the setter of `PhoneNumberEntry`

```
private string phoneNumberEntry;

    public string PhoneNumberEntry
    {
        get { return phoneNumberEntry; }
        set
        {
            phoneNumberEntry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PhoneNumberEntry");
        }
    }
```